# How can I convert the string "Hello this is world" to "world is this Hello" in CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I reverse the string "Hello world I am Jack" to "Jack am I world Hello" using CSS?

For example:

Hello world this is jack

I am wondering how to convert this using CSS to

jack is this world Hello

Comment: You can't do that using CSS

Comment: The question is not 'how' but 'why'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each word is in a different html element, you can use

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: row-reverse;
justify-content: flex-end;
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.reversed {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.wrapper > * {
  margin: 0 .1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper reversed">
  <span>Hello</span>
  <span>world</span>
  <span>this</span>
  <span>is</span>
  <span>jack</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper normal">
  <span>Hello</span>
  <span>world</span>
  <span>this</span>
  <span>is</span>
  <span>jack</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to wrap your individual words in other elements, such as `<span>word</span>`, there's a means of implementing this using `direction` and `unicode-bidi`:

```css
#demo {
  /* changes the direction of in-line elements/flow content to right-to-left: */
  direction: rtl;
  /* changes the calculation process by which the browser normally evaluates
     the placement of in-line elements/flow-content: */
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  /* because direction: rtl makes content right-to-left, this float moves the 
     parent element back to the left of the screen (for us left-to-right readers): */
  float: left;
}

#demo > span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <span>Hello</span> <span>I</span> <span>am</span> <span>Jack</span>
</div>
```

But, honestly, JavaScript is cleaner and likely more reliable.

References:

- [`direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction).
- [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).
- [`unicode-bidi`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi).

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript to do this:

```
var s = "Hello world i am jack";
alert(s.split(' ').reverse().join(' '));
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dta32gs/1/)

---

If the string is in a `div`:

```
<div>Hello world I am Jack</div>
```

You can do this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dta32gs/2/)

---

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in CSS, since CSS is about formatting HTML *elements*, and words as such are not HTML elements. If you wrap each word in an element, then various approaches are possible; but if you can do that, you can probably also put the words in the desired order in the content itsel